# Interchange of limit of sum and integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $f(x)=\sin x$ , then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\int_0^1 x^kf(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1f(x)\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}x^kdx ?$$
I tried by dominating convergence theorem if it true or not but I'm not able to conclude it properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The sum is finite so this is true by linearity of the integral.

Comment: Does dominating convergence theorem have anything to do with this ?

Comment: For proving this statement, I don't think it does. Why do you think DCT has something to do with this?

Comment: @LeeLee1729 No, dominating convergence theorem has nothing to do with it, as nothing is converging to nothing. If integrability of $x^k f(x)$ is not in question and $n$ is finite, nothing else can be a problem.

Comment: @fwd since actual question  ask to find the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\times \text{Given LHS}$$ and $f(x)= \sin x$. So, I doubt and thought of DCT.

Comment: Thanks Alex Peter and fwd.

Comment: @LeeLee1729 this is a case of the XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) , you probably should have mentioned that instead.

Comment: I apologise. I have mentioned now.

Comment: It still holds because you didn't move the limit inside the integral, you just rearranged the $n$-th term of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you @fwd.